# Clojurescript + Om: wait for state change, then do something

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async, om, secretary

I am trying to make a Clojurescript app that shows recipes.

Relevant code follows (also available [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/borkdude/257b6792b62a18e034a3)):

```
(defn load-recipes [data]
  (go (if (not (:loaded? @data))
        (let [recipes-data (<! (fetch-recipes data))]
          (om/update! data :recipes recipes-data)
          (om/update! data :loaded? true))
        (println "Data already loaded"))))

(defn define-routes [data]
  (defroute home-path "/" []
    (om/update! data :view :home))
  (defroute "/random" []
    (go (loop [loaded? (:loaded? (om/value data))]
          (if-not loaded? (do (println "Waiting for data...")
                              (recur (:loaded? (om/value data))))
                  (do (om/update! data :tag
                                  (rand-nth
                                   (vec (apply set/union (map :tags (:recipes @data))))))
                      (om/update! data :view :random)))))))

(defn app-view [data owner]
  (reify
    om/IWillMount
    (will-mount [_]
      (do
        (load-recipes data)
        (define-routes data)))
    om/IDidMount
    (did-mount [_]
      #_(fetch-recipes data))
    om/IRender
    (render [_]
      (html data))))
```

What I want to accomplish:

- First fetch the recipes using an async http call. I am using cljs-http.client that returns a channel
- Define routes using the secretary library. In the /random route I want to select a random recipe. This can only happen when the data has been fetched and has been updated in the application atom.

What I get now is an infinite loop in the browser. What's happening?

Another option is wrapping all my routes who need data fetching first in a go block and put `(<! (load-recipes))` on the first line.

PS: I ended up with

```
(defn ensure-recipes-loaded [data]
  (go (if (not (:loaded? (om/value data)))
        (do (om/update! data :view :loading)
            (let [recipes-data (<! (fetch-recipes data))]
              (om/update! data :recipes recipes-data)
              (om/update! data :loaded? true)))
        (println "Data already loaded"))))

(defn define-routes [data]
  (defroute home-path "/" []
    (om/update! data :view :home))
  (defroute "/random" []
    (go
      (<! (ensure-recipes-loaded data))
      (do (om/update! data :tag
                      (rand-nth
                       (vec (apply set/union (map :tags (:recipes @data))))))
          (om/update! data :view :random))))
  (defroute "/random/:tagname" [tagname]
    (go (<! (ensure-recipes-loaded data))
        (om/update! data :tag tagname)
        (om/update! data :view :random)))

  (defroute "/recipe/:link" [link]
    (go (<! (ensure-recipes-loaded data))
        (om/update! data :view :recipe)
        (om/update! data :permalink link)))

  (defroute "*" [*]
    (go (<! (ensure-recipes-loaded data))
        (om/update! data :view :default))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `loop` construct without any (parking) channel operations inside it to wait is pretty much entirely contrary to the spirit of core.async. Keep in mind that JavaScript is single-threaded, so if you don't park a thread of execution, there's no opportunity for anything else to run.

Have a channel that you close when the loading operation is complete. Try to read from that channel when you need to block; if it returns `nil`, it's done, and if it blocks, then you have the desired operation of waiting. If you want to periodically do something while waiting, then read from both that channel and a timeout.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I posted my updated code. Please comment if it can be improved.